# How to create waypoint where I click on multiple objects and get distance to that object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an Area Target which has specific points of interest. I am using a nav Agent and when I click on a POI, the nav agent moves to that clicked point.

I am trying to add waypoint that shows ft to target, it takes on the following properties:

```
public Transform target;
```

If I say have 5 cubes (which are the 5 POIs), how do I make the code work where target is the object (cube) I clicked?

If I drag the cube (1-5), then it works to that POI.

Thanks